# Getting SVN Commit Eclipse history

Tags: svn, subclipse, eclipse-juno

Is there a simple way through the Eclipse UI to get a history of svn commits? I don't mean on specific files/folders, but in general to see the last commit (including the comment and what project/files were updated?)

I'm running Juno with Subclipse. I recently commited a set of changes in multiple packages in a project (Cleaning up some sonar violations in between tasks.) Everything seemed to work right, and the display worked as expected. However, the next time I checked Sonar, many of the violations were still present and I could swear I had just fixed them. I'm trying to get the list of files I changed so I can go back and check them individually to see if I actually did change them or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a eclipse user myself but this seems to be what you want:

http://www.eclipse.org/subversive/documentation/teamSupport/history_view.php

At the bottom it shows individual files that were changed.

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I was looking for, just couldn't find it.

Answer (score 5):

Right click on Project --> Team--> show History.. In History Tab click show all to see complete history of your project by default it shows only 25 commits.. we can set the date range too